# How to simulate a relatively slow but physics based missile launch over a small area in UE4?

Tags: physics, unreal-engine4

Here's the problem, I'm trying to simulate a missile launch over a world map that the player can essentially see the entire thing and it is essentially about 10 meters across in game. The problem is that because it is a short distance the impulse that I have to provide in order for the missile to reach the target makes it there in about 1-2 seconds. However, the ideal situation would be for it to take around 10-15 seconds.

Without messing with gravity in the project settings is there a way to slow down my physics object so that it still moves in the same parabolic arc but, just moves slower in general.

Comment: Try setting a [custom time dilation](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/CustomTimeDilation/index.html) for the missile.

Comment: That is not really an optimal solution. The problem is that it is a physics object and therefore I have to modify the global time dilation and modify the custom time dilation of every other object that I don't want to be affected.

Comment: Is the missile not an actor? I'm not sure I understand the reason a custom time dilation can't be set for the missile.

Comment: An alternative is using a [Projectile Movement Component](https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/UProjectileMovementComponent/index.html) on the missile and setting the **ProjectileGravityScale** to something between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Ruzihm yes it is an actor. However, because it is simulating physics, custom time dilation won't work on it because physics is run on the global time dilation. As far as changing around the projectile gravity scale, I've been trying to modify it but, I can't seem to get that nice parabolic movement that you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that limitation. Have you looked into increasing the [linear damping](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Physics/FrictionRestitutionAndDamping/index.html) on the missile? The downside to this is that it would affect how you calculate your launching velocity, if that's something you're already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Radial Force, you can reduce the force strength to a smaller number.

Basically, a radial force is a way to simulate a sudden force in a radius like making an explosion or something, you can fire the impulse force on Tick Event so that it is a constant force. When you add this to the actor, you can change the "impulse strength" value to let the missile move based on how strong the force is. The higher the Impulse strength, the faster the missile moves. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: Basically, a radial force is a way to simulate a sudden force in a radius like making an explosion or something, you can fire the impulse force on Tick Event so that it is a constant force. When you add this to the actor, you can change the "impulse strength" value to let the missile move based on how strong the force is. The higher the Impulse strength, the faster the missile moves. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, Ali. Please Edit your answer post and put what you wrote as a comment inside the answer. This is because not everybody is noticing the comments.

Comment: Sure thing, will do.